# Change text in tikz nodes for different slides

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, uncover

I have a tikz picture where I use `\uncover` to show different parts of the picture on different slides. However, for some of the nodes I would also like the text within the node to change depending on the slide. I am currently solving this by creating a new frame when it happens, but that means the nodes are not perfectly aligned between frames anymore. Is there a way to change the text within a node depending on the slide?

MWE (so for example make the text `\mu` switch to `\nu` on the second slide):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \uncover<1->{\node(mu){$\mu$};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You ought to be able to use all the beamer macros inside of a TikZ node as well. There might be issues of stuff “jumping around” which is a common problem and has multiple approaches. You might be interested in the [aobs-tikz](https://ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) package/library for more complex diagrams and to battle the aforementioned problem.

Comment: But how would you do it then? Something like `\uncover<1>{$\mu$}\uncover<2->{$\nu$}` inside the node doesn't work.

Comment: Does `\node(mu){$\alt<1>{\mu}{\nu}$};` work?

Comment: Yes that works! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\only`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
        \only<1>{\node[draw, minimum size=8mm, anchor=base](mu){$\mu$};}
        \only<2>{\node[draw, minimum size=8mm, anchor=base](mu){$\nu$};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Writing `\node<1>(mu){$\nu$};` might be shorter and I would suggest to use the same node name in case some other elements will reference it.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Good point.

Comment: I didn't realize it's possible to define a node with the same name multiple times, in that case this should also work, just like the comment underneath my question. Thank you!

Comment: Although, I noticed this does not solve the issue because of which I initially asked this question: If I do it this way, once the text within the nodes changes, this causes various nodes to switch position and size (because the initial text consumes more space than the text it converts to). So my follow-up question would be: how can I fix the sizes and positions of all nodes from the first slide on?

Comment: `<only>`, as in the original answer, solves for this.